# Conseguir un string que se repita sin saltos de líneas ni espacios

Tags: python, python-2.x

Estoy aprendiendo Python y se me ha planteado una duda, si yo me llamo Carlos, ¿como hago para conseguir un string que ponga CarlosCarlosCarlosCarlosCarlos? Es un ejemplo tonto sin utilidad pero no consigo pensar cómo hacerlo y obviamente debe ser posible.

Había pensado con un bucle for, pero se me generan saltos de línea.

```
for i in range (5):
    print "Carlos"
```

También había pensado en ir llenando una lista, pero se me imprime separandose las sílabas.

Seguro que hay expresión sencilla para eso pero no se me ocurre ¿me podeis orientar?

¡Salud y gracias!

Comment: Una observación personal que nada tiene que ver con la pregunta, si estás aprendiendo Python te recomendaría olvidarte de Python 2 excepto que esté justificado. A [Python 2 le quedan menos de 15 meses de soporte oficial](https://pythonclock.org), en principio no debería usarse para nuevos desarrollos, de hecho muchas librerías  están dejando de dar soporte a esta rama o lo van a a hacer en breve, por ejemplo Matplotlib 3.0 ya no soporta Python 2 y la mayoría de proyectos importantes o se han portado o se desarrollan primariamente en Python 3 como wxPython 4. Un saludo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No hace falta iterar. Multiplica la `str` las veces que necesites.

```
'Carlos' * 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Otra cosa que puedes hacer es esto:

```
for i in range (5):
    print("Carlos", end="")
```

Con el `end=""` se le quita el salto de línea al `print`

Comment: Esta sintaxis es de Python 3. Dado que el/la usuario/a no puso paréntesis en su llamada a `print` supongo que él/ella está usando Python 2.

Comment: Pero en python 2 también se pueden usar paréntesis...suponer sin aclaración es como dar un salto sin ver el camino.

Comment: Sí, en python 2 se pueden usar paréntesis, pero python2 no admite lo de `end=""`, por lo que tu respuesta no es válida para python2. Y ya que `print` sin paréntesis no es compatible con python3, no veo yo que sea dar un salto en el vacío el considerar que el código del usuario era de python2.

Comment: Para aclarar, en Python 2  `print` es una keyword, no una función builtin y por tanto no se puede llamar, "puedes usar paréntesis", pero los paréntesis son totalmente superfluos o  indican una **tupla** en el caso de más de un objeto. `print ("a", "b")` muestra `('a', 'b')` no `a b` como ocurriría en Python 3. Lo que si se puede hacer en Python >= 2.6 es usar la función `print` de Python 3 mediante `from __future__ import print_function` al inicio del script.  Esto hace que `print` pase a comportarse como la función  built-in de Python 3 y por tanto usar el parámetro `end` de la misma.